# Handling CompletionException

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am calling `getOrders` which returns a `CompletableFuture`. When order does not exist, getOrders method is returning `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException` exception with `detailedMessage` HTTP 404. How can I handle this exception returned after the `join` call? Is wrapping the error in a `try / catch` block the best way to handle it or are there any other options

```
  client.getOrders(orderId).join()


  public CompletableFuture<Orders> getOrders(String orderId) {
    
  }
```

Comment: `client.getOrders(orderId).handle((result,throwable) -> {...}).join()`